# Socket.io with Node Connection Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I got a problem, i can connect from my Unity client with socket.io to my node server, everything there works, the connection gets acknowledged.
When i want to emit a message to the connected client, the connection gets reopened, just like a new client connects, so an endless loop.

Here is the server code:

```
// require
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('client connected');
    socket.emit("test", 55555);
});

server.listen(3000);
console.log('server started');
```

The client just connects but here is the code anyway:
    private SocketIOComponent socket;

```
void Start() {
    socket = GetComponent<SocketIOComponent>();
    socket.Emit("test");
    socket.On("test", OnTest);
}

private void OnTest(SocketIOEvent e) {
    Debug.Log(e.data);
}

void Update() { }
```

I just have no idea what i am doing wrong, i did this a few times before.

Comment: That code looks right. Is there any chance that your client is mistakenly opening 2 connections, i.e Start() is getting called twice?

Comment: Im installing a different Unity Version, maybe this will help.

Comment: @Steve too bad it didnt change anything, the problem only occours if the socket.emit() function is called if i delete it it works well, also no message ever reaches my client.

Comment: So you don't get the `55555` back at the client?

Comment: @Steve no i get nothing back, in the server console 'client connected' gets called in a loop, but only after my client connected to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that this socket.io version from the asset store doesnt work anymore.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socket-io-for-unity-21721
I switched to this one here:
https://github.com/nhnent/socket.io-client-unity3d
and everything is working fine.